# C - Libraries with the same function and variable names

Tags: c, include

I want to include two libraries which i built from the source code.

To go more into detail: These libraries are in general the same, except for some parameters which are different and set by a

```
#define Mode *X*
```

X describes the mode and describes which parameter set to use. E.g.

For x = 2 i want to use

```
#define N 3
#define Q 4
```

etc

In one library my x is for example 2 and in the other 3 which makes N 4 and Q 6 e.g.

Also these libraries contain the same functions which operate little different depending mode which is set.

I Need to include both of them and keep the options open to use both parameter sets.

Any ideas how to implement this correctly and clean? The whole thing only depends on the mode and to rename all containing functions and variables is unfortunately no option. But i have access to the source code and can make some changes.

I tried to built the libraries and include them in my main program but obviously i have a lot of naming collisions and the first definition which is found by the linker is set to be correct.

Another problem is that all the header files start with e.g.

```
 #ifndef CONFIG
 #define CONFIG
```

Which is standard and ok but I have all files two times so only the first header which is included by the linker sees that it isnt already defined and for the second its already defined so none of the code below is executed by the compiler.

Has someone a good idea how to solve this elegant?

I heard something about namespaces but i am not sure if this is even available for C and the right way to go.

BR

Comment: Regarding the issue with header file inclusion, you could change the names of `CONFIG` to something more descriptive per header file. E.g., if the header files are in different directories, you could prepend the directory name to the constant name

Comment: Why can't you use `#if MODE==2 #define N 3 ...` and so on?

Comment: I did this, but if i build the libs and link them, you will still have conflicting types because the names are still the same

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to resort to loading the external libraries at run time.

If you're on Linux, you can use `dlopen` to open a library at runtime, then use `dlsym` to extract each variable and function you would want to use.

You could create a struct that would contain pointers to the variables and functions for an instance of the library, then populate a copy of the struct for each variation of the library.  From there, you would use the function pointer from the appropriate struct instance to call a particular library function.

For example, suppose you have the following library files:

x2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
    printf("in x2 foo\n");
}
```

x3.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
    printf("in x3 foo\n");
}
```

And these are compiled into libx2.so and libx3.so respectively.  Then your main source could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

struct lib {
    void (*foo)(void);
};

int main(void)
{
    struct lib lib2;
    struct lib lib3;

    void *l2 = dlopen("./libx2.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!l2) {
        printf("dlopen x2 failed: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }
    void *l3 = dlopen("./libx3.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!l3) {
        printf("dlopen x3 failed: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    lib2.foo = dlsym(l2, "foo");
    lib3.foo = dlsym(l3, "foo");

    lib2.foo();
    lib3.foo();

    dlclose(l2);
    dlclose(l3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
in x2 foo
in x3 foo
```

Comment: Thanks thats definitely a way to do it, but for my purposes too much to open the libraries dynamically every time i need them.

Is there also a way to make some variables or constants "invisible" for the outside? So that, besides some functions, the library is a closed system and you can avoid collisions?

Comment: @LykVanDyk You wouldn't open the libraries every time you call a function.  You'd do it once at the start of the program to populate one or more sets of function (and data) pointers.  Then when you need to call a function you use one of the pointers you previously stored.